# PyQt: Add qpushbutton dynamically

Tags: python, dynamic, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I am trying to figure out how to create QPushButton by pressing another QPushbutton so that I can ultimately create buttons dynamically. It seems like the initial method for creating buttons doesn't work in a function.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize   



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


    self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    

    pybutton = QPushButton('Create a button', self)
    pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
    pybutton.resize(100,100)
    pybutton.move(100, 100)        

def clickMethod(self):
    print('Clicked')
    newBtn = QPushButton('New Button', self)
    newBtn.move(0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a window is displayed, it invokes the `show()` method of its children, so the children are visible. If you want the buttons that you add afterwards to be visible you must call the `show()` method of the button

```
def clickMethod(self):
    print('Clicked')
    newBtn = QPushButton('New Button', self)
    newBtn.move(0, 0)
    newBtn.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you just need show() ,
but better if you make it in the list to controll it later , like this :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize   



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
     QMainWindow.__init__(self)
     self.i=0
     self.y=0
     self.btn=[]
     self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    
 
     pybutton = QPushButton('Create a button', self)
     pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
     pybutton.resize(100,100)
     pybutton.move(100, 100)        

    def clickMethod(self):
     print('Clicked')
     self.btn.append( QPushButton('New Button', self))
     
     self.btn[-1].move(self.i, self.y)
     self.i=self.i+50
     self.y=self.y+50
     self.btn[-1].show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```